# Is std::iostream non-blocking?

Tags: c++, iostream

According to the boost reference for Boost.Iostreams (In section 3.6, at the very bottom):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html

> Although the Boost.Iostreams Filter and Device concepts can
>   accommodate non-blocking i/o, the C++ standard library stream and
>   stream buffer interfaces cannot, since they lack a means to
>   distinguish between temporary and permanent failures to satisfy a read
>   or write request

However, the function `std::istream::readsome` appears to be non-blocking, in that the available characters will be immediately returned, without a blocking (except for a RAM copy) wait. My understanding is that:

`std::istream::read` will block until `eof` or number of characters read.

`std::istream::readsome` will return immediately with characters copied from the internal buffer.

Comment: readsome() doesn't do what you think it does. All it does is return you characters which are already buffered internally, but are yet unread.

Comment: That is what I think it does (perhaps my confusion lies elsewhere?). Surely this can be regarded as non-blocking, as opposed to waiting until the character becomes available to read? I'll clarify my understand above....

Comment: From cppreference: "The behavior of this function is highly implementation-specific."

Comment: @NeilButterworth I just read this section and understood it as highly implementation dependent how many data it will return, but what it returns is immediately

Comment: I might be wrong, but my understanding is that "they lack a means to [..] to satisfy a read or write request" and non-blocking `readsome` is both correct, but there is no contradiction, because `readsome` does not issue a read request

Comment: For non-blocking I/O you'd need something like a `would_block` return code. `std::istream` does not support that.

Comment: btw I cannot find the quote on the link you provide

Comment: @tobi303 I've added the section that the quote is in. The url links to the index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with you that `readsome` is not a blocking operation. However, as specified, it is wholly inadequate as an interface for performing what is usually called "non-blocking I/O".

First, there is no guarantee that `readsome` will *ever* return new data, even if it is available. So to guarantee you actually make progress, you must use one of the blocking interfaces eventually.

Second, there is no way to know when `readsome` will return data. There is no way to "poll" the stream, or to get a "notification" or "event" or "callback". A usable non-blocking interface needs at least one of these.

In short, `readsome` appears to be a half-baked and under-specified attempt to provide a non-blocking interface to I/O streams. But I have never seen it used in production code, and I would not expect to.

I think the Boost documentation overstates the argument, because as you observe, `readsome` is certainly capable of distinguishing temporary from permanent failure. But their conclusion is still correct for the reasons above.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it's not an ideal interface. My code is calling readsome using a deadline timer until eof exception. What would you suggest as an alternative? I have to pass a stream to a socket interface.

Comment: @PeterBingham: Sure, or just fire off a thread and use blocking operations. But neither of these has much to do with this question or my answer.

Answer (score 4):

When looking into non-blocking portability, I didn't find anything in the C++ standard library that looked like it did what you think it does.

If your goal is portability, my interpretation was that the section that mattered most was this:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/readsome

> For example, when used with std::ifstream, some library
>   implementations fill the underlying filebuf with data as soon as the
>   file is opened (and readsome() on such implementations reads data,
>   potentially, but not necessarily, the entire file), while other
>   implementations only read from file when an actual input operation is
>   requested (and readsome() issued after file opening never extracts any
>   characters).

This says that different implementations that use the iostream interface are allowed to do their work lazily, and readsome() doesn't guarantee that the work even gets kicked off.

However, I think your interpretation that readsome is guaranteed not to block is true.

Comment: I think you cut important part of the quote "For example, when used with std::ifstream, some library implementations fill the underlying filebuf with data as soon as the file is opened ..." I understand this as `readsome` never really reading data, but the `ifstream` may read data already when the file is opened and only then it can be returned from `readsome`

Comment: I'm using boost::asio. One of the APIs in my asio project require an iostream but to be non-blocking I want to only read what is available.

Comment: @tobi303 fair enough, added it in, as well as the link to the reference material

Comment: sorry now I really want to understand it.... cppref also says "Extracts up to count immediately available characters..." which I read as: readsome is guaranteed to never "kick off" any acutaly reading, but really is non-blocking (but still practically useless for non-blocking reading from a stream)

Comment: @PeterBingham I'd guess I'd argue that if you had to use iostream and you absolutely could not block, a thread is going to be required somewhere. If you want to rely on implementation specific behavior, thats up to you. I think it also depends on what specific flavor of iostream you actually use.

Comment: @tobi303 right, readsome doesn't block. But the way I interpret the above is that the io may not start, as the behavior there is implementation defined. Just because you call file.open(), for instance, doesn't mean the file contents are available on all platforms. Further, even if it is now, based on the way it reads, its not guaranteed to always be that way.

Comment: @Josh Surely the example you have given is for a single implementation of the iostream interface and even in the case given all calls to readsome will still be non-blocking (regardless of whether it reads data or not). I have implemented my own stream using the iostream interface and can guarantee the behaviour with regards to availability of data.

Comment: @PeterBingham err, now I'm very confused. If you've defined a fully custom iostream implementation, of course it can be non-blocking? your question implies (at least in my mind) that you are interested in the behavior of iostream in general. Anyway, I edited the answer to clarify that I think readsome does not block, based on the way it reads.

Comment: Yes, I am. As far as I am aware the Boost.Iostreams derived from the std::stream interface. I've implemented my stream using devices and filters as described in the link in the question. But regardless and even for your example (std::ifstream) the interface will be non-blocking, unless I've misunderstood?

Comment: @PeterBingham I think you are correct in that narrow scope. I guess my point was that readsome() doesn't do anything unless the buffer is getting filled, and for the more general iostream case, there is no such guarantee that the buffer is getting filled without some blocking call. If you have a custom iostream, I think you are fine.

Comment: @Josh then the comment on the boost link seems confusing, since it is related to the design of custom streams.

Comment: @PeterBingham i guess? your original question as i read it had a link to the standard getsome() reference as well. You appeared to be trying to refute or work around their claim that std iostreams were, in general, not designed to be a blocking api. I didn't see any reference to building a custom stream implementation in the body of your question. Perhpas I misunderstood.

Comment: @Josh I think you're correct, my comment was a bit misleading. The 'stream I've implemented' is a pipe from an asio tcp socket, through filters and finally into a std::istream. The client gets the std::istream and I need for him to be able to make non-blocking calls to get data from the std::istream.